# Find g(x) such that $G(x) = g(x) + |x|$ and the function $g$ are differentiable at $0$

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

Is it possible to find a function $g$ such that the function
$G(x) = g(x) + |x|$ is differentiable at $0$ and the function $g$ is differentiable at $0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $G$ is differentiable at $0$ and $g$ is differentiable at $0$, then we know that $G-g$ is also differentiable at $0$. However $(G-g)(x)=|x|$, which is not differentiable at $0$. So at least one of $g$ and $G$ cannot be differentiable at $0$.

Answer (score 1):

If $G(x)$ and $g(x)$ are differentiable then so is $G(x)-g(x)$ by the linearity of the derivative. This contradicts the fact that $G(x)-g(x)=|x|$ which is not differentiable.